# Error Installing npm package within embedded node in spring boot project on windows

Tags: node.js, spring-boot

```
PS C:\Users\zjdan\vscodeprojects\springboot\ch2> .\node\npm.cmd i parcel
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\zjdan\vscodeprojects\springboot\ch2\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zjdan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-16T02_02_52_128Z-debug-0.log
```

No environment variable verified. No installed nodejs version installed on windows.

Comment: problem resolved after installing Nodejs packages in Visual Studio Community 2022. Not sure why windows would need these packages if I am creating a nodejs front-end using standalone node module in a spring boot application?